# Django + RestFramework + twilio: Getitng status call back sid

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, twilio

I am trying something that I believe is so simple and I it works fine when i test my end point with postman, however when the site is up, is when i get "error"

These are my current settings:

```
twilio==6.29.1
Django==2.0.7
djangorestframework==3.9.4
Python 3.6.8
```

After sending an SMS with twilio:

```
client = Client(key1,key2)
message = client.api.account.messages.create(
    body= request.data["Body"],
    to= request.data["toNumber"],
    status_callback='https://myurl',
    from_= request.data["fromNumber"]
)
```

I have set up the call back

```
class SMSCallBack(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):  
        print(request.GET)
        print(request.GET.getlist('SmsSid'))
        return Response({'xxx': 'xxx'})
```

However this is my respond in the logs

```
<QueryDict: {}>
[]
```

If I try to do the same in postman I get

```
<QueryDict: {'SmsSid': ['asd']}>
['asd']
```

Now I am guessing with postman that Ihave set it correctly (POST, and add in params tab a value) as the console log from twilio is indicating that one of the multiple params they are sending is the SmsSid

[image: Twilio debug console]

I am pretty new with Django and python, so perhaps is there something i am missing when trying to get the incoming parameters?

When I try

```
request.POST.getlist('SmsSid')
```

My result is:

```
2019-07-15T05:15:25.735240+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.65.77.132 - - [15/Jul/2019:05:15:25 +0000] "POST /XXXX/smscallback/ HTTP/1.1" 415 100 "-" "TwilioProxy/1.1"
2019-07-15T05:15:25.738919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/XXXX/smscallback/" host=XXX.com request_id=3c5b81c2-003b-461a-8bd9-3e79d4545a9a fwd="3.94.8.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=783ms status=415 bytes=346 protocol=https
```

When I try in postman i get

[]

Comment: you have used a `post method` but trying to get the callback parameters from `GET`. arent you supposed to do `request.POST.getlist('SmsSid')`

Comment: Exprator I have edited the question to display what I get when i try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio is going to make a POST request to your statusCallback endpoint. So the data will be in the request body, under `request.POST` not under `request.GET`.

Your code also shows that you are using the `JSONParser` to parse the incoming request. Twilio sends the request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you should be using the `FormParser` instead.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Awesome, one off topic question, back in the console I get error 415, it says possible error Content-Type doesn’t match actual content, what do I need to return to avoid twilio showing this warning?

Comment: I'm not sure that is off topic, it's your server returning the 415 and it's because it's not receiving a request that it's expecting. Hopefully updating to use the right incoming parser will mean it does expect the input and returns a 200.